# Timing Processing Stripe Webhooks and Saving Changes to Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stripe-payments

I have an asp.net web application that uses Stripe to handle subscription payments. I'm running into a scenario where Stripe is sending webhook events before I've saved the changes to my database, so when I go to process the webhooks my data is not in sync. As an example:

1. User upgrades from Free to Paid plan
2. I call Stripe's update subscription endpoint to change user from free to paid plan
3. Stripe triggers payment succeeded webhook
4. My application processes the webhook and I successfully locate the subscription object in my database, but it is not set to the new plan yet
5. Call to Stripe update subscription in step 2 returns as a success and my  application updates the database, assigning it to the new plan

So, the issue is that Stripe's webhooks are fired before the update subscription call finishes. I don't want to update my database until the call comes back to make sure my database doesn't get out of sync.

My current thought is to queue Stripe webhook events as they come in and process them after some delay. But this raises a few questions:

1. How long do I set the delay for?
2. How do I know when I process the webhook that the original call has completed and my database has been updated?
3. Are there any other gotchas I haven't thought of?

Comment: Stripe doesn't guarantee the timing of webhooks, but one thought here --- what hooks are you most interested in? Those pertaining to automatic renewals? When you're upgrading a subscription or making another synchronous request, you have a response from the API, so you don't necessarily need to look at the webhook; you could check if request id on an Event is not null (meaning it came from an API request and not an action like an automatic renewal) https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-request-id, if it is discard the hook

Comment: Hey Austin .. I have similar problem, Wondering if you have solved this? If yes, What approach did you take?